# Is there a better way to generate my main index page in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

so I've created a function that works but I feel it is a very janky set up. So I'm creating a single page site that will generate a gallery displaying two images at once. With that being said the query kind of is the less important part of my site since it is only generating the event images. I do how ever want to allow the user to click on each image in the gallery to be brought to another page which will be a post of all the images for the particular gallery. Can you look over my code and let me know if there is a better way. I'm fairly new to php and wp themes.

Thanks!

```
if( ! function_exists( 'alpha_generate_page' ) ) {
function alpha_generate_page() {
    if ( have_posts() ) :

            if ( is_single() ) : get_template_part( 'temp/events_single', get_post_format() );
                else : get_template_part( 'main', get_post_format() );
            endif;

        else: get_template_part( 'main', get_post_format() );
    endif;
}
```

}

Comment: I couldn't really comment on "jankiness" as WordPress often seems to look a bit that way, but it is done "in the style of" how it works. This plugin might be handy - some prefer plugins to home grown code https://wordpress.org/plugins/get-the-image/  It gets the images from posts with their associated links. Pagination might be an issue if it is inside the loop and the gallery needs grouping into pages, but if it is a continuously scrollable page that won't matter.https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: This might provide pointers if you have featured images or thumbnails in your posts https://wordpress.org/support/topic/retrieveing-featured-image-url They said they had been looking for this for 5 years in the posts on this page - make sure you use the fixed one.

Comment: You might also like to explore using shortcodes if neatness on the page itself is you main goal: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/